# Pass variable from jinja2 template to python

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

Sorry if this is a noob question I am still learning. I have passed a variable from python code to a jinja2 HTML template to set up a URL, like this:

`<a href="/delete/{{ result.key.id() }}">Delete</a>`

When this link is pressed it should run a query that deletes the entity with that ID. But when the link is pressed it goes to /delete/1827424298 for example, which results in a 404 error as the request handler doesn't exist.

I need to pass that ID back into my python code so it can run a method to delete the entity with that same ID. How do I go about doing this? Using webapp2 if that is important.

```
class DeleteRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get():


    template = template_env.get_template('myrequests.html')
    context = {

        'results': results.key.id()

    }

    self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
```

EDIT: I've added my delete handler - it is incomplete as I have yet to add the query to delete the entity. My thinking behind it so far is I can grab the `results.key.id()` from the jinja2 template and put it into `results` but I am not sure if this would work.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You know that the 404 happens because you haven't written written a handler that deals with that route; so what's stopping you from writing one?

Comment: The IDs are generated randomly in cloud datastore every time a new entity is created. I then retrieve all these entities and put them into a HTML table with a delete link next to them like in my example. Because the IDs are random I cannot set up a handler. I just need a way to delete entities by their ID.

Comment: But I don't understand why you say "Because the IDs are random I cannot set up a handler". Of course you can.

Comment: Oh I can? Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: What is you delete method route? Add your delete method and route.. as per 404 means the route not created

Comment: It's better to add your code to your question. Then people can easily answer

Comment: I have added my code with my thinking behind it. It doesn't work however because I get 404 error and I am not sure if what this would even work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I *think* what you're confused about is how to set up a route handler with a dynamic part to the URL. It's a shame that this is completely skipped over in the webapp2 tutorial, as it's a fundamental part of writing any web application. However, it is covered well in [the guide to routing](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html), which you should read.

At its simplest, it's just a matter of putting a regex in the route:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ...
    (r'/delete/(\d+)', MyDeleteHandler),
])
```

which will now route any URL of the form `/delete/<number>/` to your deletion handler.

The ID that you pass in the URL will be the first positional argument to the handler method:

```
class MyDeleteHandler:
    def get(self, item_id):
        key = ndb.Key(MyModel, item_id)   # or whatever
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I am after. How can I work with the ID from the URL after the handler is invoked? Ideally I would like to take the ID from the URL and put it into a new variable in my delete handler so that I can use it in a query.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer, but I've expanded it.

Comment: Note also, you really shouldn't make destructive changes - especially deletions - with a GET from a simple link; you should use a form and POST.